# How to fix compile error: Invalid use of property

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to drag all the formulas from a workbook from column AQ2 to BF, but when I'm assisgning the count for the lastrow variable, it keeps giving me an error

Already tried just doing it without the variable lastrow, but it's giving me the same error

```
Option Explicit
Dim mt_roster As String
Dim roster As String
Dim wkb_1 As Workbook
Dim wkb_2 As Workbook
Dim ws_1 As Worksheet
Dim ws_2 As Worksheet
Dim rng_1 As Range
Dim rng_2 As Range
Dim lastrow As Range

Sub mtm_roster()

' mtm_roster Macro

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    open_rosters

    With wkb_1
        wkb_1.Activate
        Set ws_1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng_1 = ws_1.Columns("A:AQ")
        rng_1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

    With wkb_2
        wkb_2.Activate
        Set ws_2 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng_2 = ws_2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
        rng_2.Select
    End With

    rng_2.Copy
    rng_1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wkb_2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    With wkb_1
        wkb_1.Activate
        ws_1.Activate
        Set lastrow = Range("A1")
        lastrow.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count
        Range("AQ2:BF" & lastrow).FillDown

    End With
```

I'm trying to drag the formulas from AQ:BF all the way down but I'm still missing that part.

Comment: Try the answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    With wkb_1
        Set ws_1 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng_1 = ws_1.Columns("A:AQ")
        rng_1.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    End With

    With wkb_2
        Set ws_2 = .Worksheets("Sheet1")
        Set rng_2 = ws_2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    End With

    rng_2.Copy
    rng_1.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wkb_2.Close SaveChanges:=False

    Dim LastRow As Long
    With ws_1
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("AQ2:BF" & LastRow).FillDown
    End With
```